# ASP.NET MVC Canadian Province Drop Down List

Tags: asp.net-mvc, drop-down-menu

Anyone have have a dropdownlist helper method with a list of Canadian Provinces?

Based upon this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/289048/asp-net-mvc-us-state-drop-down-list) I was looking to find a Canadian Province equivalent. Hopefully this will save someone some extra typing, or lead to an even better answer.

Comment: what exactly is the question?

Comment: I changed it to a question, and then gave a possible answer below.

Comment: @annakata There really isn't a question here, but it's an extension of the answer to another question that has a similar name "ASP.NET MVC US State Drop Down List", but this solution is for Canadian provinces, instead of US states. The first sentance of this question references that original question. (What's a "province"? I don't know. The only things I was taught about Canada in American public schools, were it's just like the US but it's north of here is nothing but tundra.)

Comment: @Adam Porad, "The only things I was taught about Canada in American public schools, were it's just like the US but it's north of here is nothing but tundra.", That's me exactly. I've never had to create a Canadian drop down before, and was surprised I didn't find one on StackOverflow.

Comment: @AdamPorad As a Canadian living in the southern part of Canada, as most of us do, its a hell of a lot warmer here and nicer that places like Minnesota, North Dakota, Michigan, Wisconsin, Montana etc. Have a look at the map some time. Those states are further north than where most people live in Canada.

Answer (score 7):

```
public class CanadianProvinces
{
    public static readonly IDictionary<string, string> ProvinceDictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>
                                                                             {
                                                                                 {"ALBERTA", "AB"},
                                                                                 {"BRITISH COLUMBIA", "BC"},
                                                                                 {"MANITOBA", "MB"},
                                                                                 {"NEW BRUNSWICK", "NB"},
                                                                                 {"NEWFOUNDLAND AND LABRADOR", "NL"},
                                                                                 {"NORTHWEST TERRITORIES", "NT"},
                                                                                 {"NOVA SCOTIA", "NS"},
                                                                                 {"NUNAVUT", "NU"},
                                                                                 {"ONTARIO", "ON"},
                                                                                 {"PRINCE EDWARD ISLAND", "PE"},
                                                                                 {"QUEBEC", "QC"},
                                                                                 {"SASKATCHEWAN", "SK"},
                                                                                 {"YUKON", "YT"},
                                                                             };

    public static SelectList ProvinceSelectList
    {
        get { return new SelectList(ProvinceDictionary, "Value", "Key"); }
    }

}
```

And then it is used in the following manner:

```
<%= Html.DropDownList("province", CanadianProvinces.ProvinceSelectList)%>
```

Comment: +1 Awesome.  Thanks for this.  Very timely.  Not for Canadian provinces but for a host of other guff.

Answer (score 4):

Mixed case *in case* somebody needs it (edit if there are typos):

```
public class CanadianProvinces
{
    public static readonly IDictionary<string, string> ProvinceDictionary =
        new Dictionary<string, string>
            {
                {"Alberta", "AB"},
                {"British Columbia", "BC"},
                {"Manitoba", "MB"},
                {"New Brunswick", "NB"},
                {"Newfoundland and Labrador", "NL"},
                {"Northwest Territories", "NT"},
                {"Nova Scotia", "NS"},
                {"Nunavut", "NU"},
                {"Ontario", "ON"},
                {"Prince Edward Island", "PE"},
                {"Quebec", "QC"},
                {"Saskatchewan", "SK"},
                {"Yukon", "YT"}
            };

    public static SelectList ProvinceSelectList
    {
        get { return new SelectList(ProvinceDictionary, "Value", "Key"); }
    }
}
```